# Line tracing folowing a path of an almost connected components

Tags: image-processing, matlab, periodic, ocr

say we have a binary image like the one in below

i would like to extract each black line, even if it's not almost connected

i have marked here in red, example of lines that correspond to those to be extracted

**the purpose here is to extract lines a handwritten text ! **

[image]
[image]
[image]

any suggestions !! Thanks

Comment: Please post an image without the red lines, so that other people will have a change to play around with it

Comment: Is the first and second image a processing that you did for the third?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

- Use FFT2 to find angle of text and approximate spaces between lines
- Rotate the image to be at 0 angle
- Sum the image column-wise
- Find threshold that splits lines of text from non text lines
- Show lines on rotated image.

It can be improved by finding a more complex curve (rather than line).

Here are the results:

**Original**
[image]

**After rotation**
[image]

**Sum of rotated image column-wise**
[image]

**Final results**
[image]

And the code is:

```
%% 1) Read image
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbHTp.jpg');
im = im(:,:,2);
im = double(im < 100);
im = padarray(im,[40 0]);
figure();imshow(im);

%% 2) Find approximate line spacing
F = fftshift(fft2(im));
% figure;imagesc(log(abs(fftshift(fft2(im)))));
[~,iMax] = max(F(:));
[r1,c1] = ind2sub(size(F),iMax);
F(iMax) = 0;
[~,iMax2] = max(F(:));
[r2,c2] = ind2sub(size(F),iMax2);
lineSpaceY = size(im,1)/ abs(r2-r1);
lineSpaceX = size(im,2)/ abs(c2-c1);
angleDeg = abs(90-rad2deg( atan2(lineSpaceX,lineSpaceY)));
imr = imrotate(im,angleDeg);
figure;imshow(imr);

%% 3) Take a look at 1D signal
S = mean(imr,2);
isText = S > max(S)/2;
isText = imclose(isText,strel('line',lineSpaceY/10,90));
% figure(); plot(isText,'o-');
rp = regionprops(isText,'Centroid');
centerY = cat(1,rp.Centroid);
centerY = centerY(:,2);

%% 4) Show final results
figure();imshow(imr);
for i=1:numel(centerY);
    hold on;
    plot( [0,size(im,2)],[centerY(i) centerY(i)],'g','LineWidth',2);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the lines aren't connected, apply a morphological opening operation to make them so (see morphologyEx in OpenCV).

Now, assuming you have a connected black region, you could apply iterative thining to obtain the skeleton. Or refer to already available ideas such as [this one](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/) or [this one](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3207/what-is-a-good-thinning-algorithm-for-getting-the-skeleton-of-characters-for-ocr/).